# How to fix `Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" framework...`

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I got this error 
`Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore.` after checkout a project from company repository and rebuild on my machine.
When I try to install .Net461 (downloaded from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=49982)) they said

> .NET Framework 4.6.1 or a later update is already installed on this computer.

This is all .NET framework versions on my machine (Windows 10 1703)

```
PS C:\Users\longnx\Downloads> & '.\check-dotnet-framework-version (1).ps1'

PSChildName                      Version        Release
-----------                      -------        -------
v2.0.50727                       2.0.50727.4927
v3.0                             3.0.30729.4926
Windows Communication Foundation 3.0.4506.4926
Windows Presentation Foundation  3.0.6920.4902
v3.5                             3.5.30729.4926
Client                           4.7.03062      461814
Full                             4.7.03062      461814
Client                           4.0.0.0


PS C:\Users\longnx\Downloads>
```

How can I fix this error?

---

update on 2020-05-26:
for anyone face this problem, I don't suggest this but from my experience, I've uninstalled and reinstall visual studio, and problem gone.

Comment: If you right-click the project in the solution explorer and open properties, under the application option on the left, what is set for the `Target Framework` field?

Comment: @Dortimer  It's 4.6.1 https://imgur.com/a/Ab2OJNN

Comment: I'd follow the link provided by the installer and try uninstalling it and reinstalling it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/troubleshoot-blocked-installations-and-uninstallations. I'm not convinced that the PowerShell command will show what you're looking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" in the "TargetFrameworks"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833741/your-project-does-not-reference-netframework-version-v4-6-2-framework-add-a)

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I found this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/312180/projects-fail-to-build-in-1580-due-to-errors-from.html) from a google search and tried it and it fixed my issue so I thought I might share that **deleting the obj folders** seems to work.

As it states in forum:

> I had the same with an old project (after using git to move to an old version locally). Deleting the 'obj' folders fixed the issue, clean is insufficient.

Two users found that this fix the issue. Most also found doing a clean and then removing the obj folder by hand then redoing a nuget restore seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 15):

The error can be solved by deleting the obj folder. But, if you have more than one project in the solution, targeting and deleting all the obj folders can be burdensome. So you can run this PowerShell command in the root of your code repository (or in the solution folder) to recursively find and delete obj folders and their content.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter obj -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: This is a massive help.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Most of the time when I face this error I just Delete or Rename the OBJ folder and try to run Visual Studio as Administrator (don't make much of difference, but helps when I download project from some tutorial website) and build the Application again.

But if that don't work then check of version of NuGet package compatibility with .net version in project setting/properties page, having to get proper NuGet package and .net version is a must for building and program. Also removing and reinstalling Visual Studio and installing that again is never an option, as it takes time to uninstall and install again.